# Create and approve PayPal subscription after invoice status is paid

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I am generating one PayPal invoice through API and send it to user for payment. after the user pays that invoice the status of invoice is changed to paid. Now I need to start a subscription because the user paid the invoice.
When I create a subscription it always give me **"approval-pending"** status . I want to set subscription status as **"Active"** because the user already paid for it through the invoice.

Answer (score 0):

Invoicing and Subscriptions are two separate things. There is no crossover between them. You use one, or you use the other, as their own ways of receiving a payment.

To send an invoice from a PayPal account, use:

- live: https://www.paypal.com/invoice
- sandbox: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/invoice

...or the invoicing API as desired.

To create and manage subscription plans, use:

- live: https://www.paypal.com/billing/plans
- sandbox: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/billing/plans

... or the Subscriptions API if desired. In the account interface after setting up a plan, use the three dots menu to copy button code or a link for it. Alternatively, follow [the subscriptions integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/) to make a button. Any created subscription, be it via a button click or API call, starts in a created state and pending approval until some payer signs in and confirms their subscription (i.e. gives approval)

---

Paying for an invoice has nothing to do with subscriptions, and will not approve any subscription. There is no way for a subscription to be approved that does not involve the user signing in and approving it, via its own button or link (nothing to do with invoices).

If you want to solicit subscriptions via an "Invoice", send your own invoice message (not a PayPal invoice) and include the subscription link, or a link to your own page's invoice view with a subscription button.